# Unknown buckets stored in my Google Cloud Platform storage

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a bunch of buckets in my Google Cloud Platform storage, and I'm not sure where they come from as I have never stored anything in the storage in the past.

[image: v]

What are these buckets for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud Storage is used as backend of several product. When you build a GCF (Cloud Functions), an APp Engine or you store a Container, the data behind the container created (for Cloud Functions and App Engine) need to reside somewhere. And it's on this special buckets.

You find the artifact buckets EU and US, you should have container in `gcr.io` and `eu.gcr.io`, you should have an app engine in US, and deployed at least 2 function, one in europe-west2 and one in us-central1.

Main problem today (and there is side discussion with Google on this): no automatic cleaning is performed on these buckets.

Comment: Great, thank you. What is the App Engine specifically?

Comment: The `nemo-dev-1b0bc.appspot.com` is this one for App Engine. But the sources are sent to the cloud before the container creation. That's why you have a staging, a temporary location before deploying.